# Unable to take video path input for cv2.VideoCapture() with pyqt threading

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, qthread, qpixmap

I want to use the files selected from QFileDialog() to emit frames instead of writing the path for cv2 capture or taking arguments from command line each time. Also i will use another push buttons to toggle through the list of video files again to be displayed on the GUI. So i will also want these file paths to be further fed to the loop.
Also is there a way to clear pixmap before displaying another file ?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QMessageBox , QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPixmap, QColor, QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QRegExp, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import pathlib
import cv2
import time
from PIL import Image


class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def run(self):
        # capture from path file
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/video.mp4')
        while True:
            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)


class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = UIVideo()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.ui.trainNewInput.clicked.connect(self.pick_new)
        self.ui.detect.clicked.connect(self.file_detect)
        self.ui.video_index=0

    def file_detect(self):
        # create the video capture thread
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        # connect its signal to the update_image slot
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()


    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.ui.photo_img.setPixmap(qt_img)
    

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(640, 640, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


    def pick_new(self):
        self.ui.dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        self.ui.folder_path = self.ui.dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")
        print(self.ui.folder_path)
        self.ui.file_name = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.ui.folder_path):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp4') or file.endswith('.avi'):
                    self.ui.file_name.append(file)

        print(self.ui.file_name)
        video_path = "videos/"+ self.ui.file_name[self.ui.video_index]
```